# MYSQL chave primária é possível criar uma máscara de preenchimento AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma chave primária, aaa-0000 como máscara e ainda ser `auto_increment`, exemplo aaa-0000, aaaa-0001, assim por diante.
Se sim, como fazer?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplique a máscara no momento de exibir.

```
$db = [conexao e leitura do banco];
foreach ($db as $v) {
    //iterando os dados extraídos do banco
    echo 'aaa-'.str_pad($v['id'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).PHP_EOL;
}
```

<sub>(o código acima é didático, com propósito ilustrativo)</sub>

output:

id 1 mostrará: aaa-0001

id 10 mostrará: aaa-0010

id 100 mostrará: aaa-0100

Consulte: [str_pad()](http://php.net/str_pad)

Comment: Valeu mesmo, vou fazer o teste